# HttpPost passing JSON data with authentication

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a web service by passing JSON data. The web service accepts the authentication, where we need to pass the username and password to authenticate.
I am sorry guys, I couldn't disclose the URL and the Username.

Below is my method to do the job.

```
private static void MakeRequest(string url, string user_name)
       {
           try
           {
               var webAddr = url;
               var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
               httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json;";
               httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
               //password is blank
               var credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(user_name + ":" + "");
               httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);

               using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
               {
                   string json = "{\"x\":\"true\"}";

                   streamWriter.Write(json);
                   streamWriter.Flush();
               }

               var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
               using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
               {
                   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               throw;
           }
}
```

When I call the method by passing URL and the username, it is returning error as "**The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.**"
I guess I am not using the proper authentication method.

Please help.

Comment: 422 errors usually indicate that your JSON data is well-formed, but has semantical errors, meaning the content is somehow malformed.

Comment: If I am passing "" data also as JSON, then also it is giving me the same error. How do I make sure that I am using the write code to authenticate?

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay try this: `string json = "{\"x\":true}";`

Comment: @Zaitsman what is the difference between string json = "{\"x\":true}"; and string json = "{\"x\":\"true\"}";

Comment: @praveen.upadhyay if your action expects a boolean datatype, sending "true" might not deserialize correctly as technically this is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Is "X" valid attribute parameter to update or create your object ? Because when trying to create or update an object with invalid or missing attribute parameters, you will get a 422 Unprocessable Entity response.

Comment: My only question is, I am doing something wrong with the authentication or not? X is just mentioned there for an example.

Comment: I think your problem was not arised from authentication issues, if so you would get authenticaiton error respond, something like 401,403 etc. Problem is your request payload ! Looking at the description of 422: The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.

Comment: It means problem is at Web Service side?

Comment: May be! You should check out web service side to fix the problem.